# react-native-tesseract-ocr whitelisting numbers only brings wrong values with same image

Tags: react-native, ocr, tesseract

I am using [react-native-tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr) to get only numbers from an image but when I add whitelisting and blacklisting, The results are inconsistent for the same image. Example using this image [image: Image Used]

The aim is to get number 2 at the bottom right of image.

here are the inconsistencies, 
When I use the options

```
const tessOptions = {
  whitelist: null, 
  blacklist: '1234567890\'!"#$%&/()={}[]+*-_:;<>'
};
RNTesseractOcr.recognize(imgPath, lang, tessOptions)
```

I get this result

```
'OCR Result: ', 'Tms IS a small demunshanon pdime ,\n\n‘us‘ «m use In me Vmua‘ Mechamcs “Anna‘s Mme ten And more\n\num And mare ten And more taxi And mare um\n\nAnd mare text And more text And mare ten And more ‘exl, And mare\num And mare ten Bonng‘ zzzzz And mare text And mm text And\nmare um And mare ten, And more text And mare ten And more ‘exl,\nAnd mare text And more text\n\nAnd mare text And more text And mare ten And more ‘exl, And mare\num And mare ten And more taxi Even mom, Cunnnued an Page 2 ,'
```

When I use options

```
const tessOptions = {
  whitelist: "0123456789", 
  blacklist: "!?@#$%&*()<>_-+=/:;'\"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
};
```

I get this result

```
'OCR Result: ', '1211215 2 2211211122112215112212121 21211212 7\n\n12222221 2222111 2212 111212221 2112211211122 2122211212 2212112 12122 22121 1112122\n\n2222 21111 2112112 12122 22121 111212222121 21111 211212 22122\n\n21121 2112112 221222 22121 1112112 2222 21111 2112112 12122 22121 1112222211 22111 211212\n2222 21111 2112112 12122 521121222222 21121 2112122 221222 22121 111212 2222 21111\n211212 2222 21121 2112112 221222 22121 1112112 2222 21111 2112112 12122 22121 1112222211\n21121 2112112 221222 22121 1112112 2222\n\n21121 2112112 221222 22121 1112112 2222 21111 2112112 12122 22121 1112222211 22111 211212\n2222 21111 2112112 12122 22121 111212222121 51211 11121122 0211211122211 221 112212 2 2'
```

Yes the result is numbers but where do they come from?, Does anyone have a clear example on whitelisting only numbers or I use the first option then filter the numbers manually with javascript ?

Comment: When you whitelist or blacklist something it doesn't mean that those symbols would be ignored in the original document. They won't or will be considered as OCR result for the symbol. So if you blacklist everything except for digits - `A Simple PDF File` would be processed and most credible digits that represent that image would be presented to you as output

Comment: Thanks @DmitriiZ for the eye opener, Do you know how I can get the 2 at the bottom?

Comment: Don't blacklist or whitelist anything, just look for digits in the output